# how to appliying mvc in java with mysql without frameworks

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller

i just learned MVC design pattern using java, i have some problem with my MVC, the problem is why the data cannot inserted into database,,

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



 public class Pembayaran {
 private int bayar,kembalian,total;
 private String terbilangBayar,terbilangTotal;
 Koneksi koneksi= new Koneksi();
 String pesan;
 public String getPesan(){
    return pesan;
 }
public void setPesan(String pesan){
    this.pesan=pesan;
}
public int getBayar() {
    return bayar;
}

public void setBayar(int bayar) {
    this.bayar = bayar;
}

public int getKembalian() {
    return kembalian;
}

public void setKembalian(int kembalian) {
    this.kembalian = kembalian;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getTerbilangBayar() {
    return terbilangBayar;
}

public void setTerbilangBayar(String terbilangBayar) {
    this.terbilangBayar = terbilangBayar;
}

public String getTerbilangTotal() {
    return terbilangTotal;
}

public void setTerbilangTotal(String terbilangTotal) {
    this.terbilangTotal = terbilangTotal;
}

public boolean simpan(){
   boolean adaKesalahan=false;
   Connection connection;
   boolean simpan;
           PreparedStatement pst;
    if((connection=koneksi.getConnection())!=null){


        String query="insert into pembayaran(bayar,total,kembalian) values(?,?,?)";
       try {
           int jumlahSimpan;
           simpan=true;

           pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
           pst.setInt(1, bayar);
           pst.setInt(2, total);
           pst.setInt(3, kembalian);
           jumlahSimpan=pst.executeUpdate();

           pst.close();
           connection.close();
           if(simpan==true){
               if(jumlahSimpan<1){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"model error");
               }
           }
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Pembayaran.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           pesan="error : model";

       }

    }
    return !adaKesalahan;
}
}
```

this is the controller

```
 package controller;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import model.Pembayaran;
 import view.FormPembayaran;
 import view.MainForm;


public class PembayaranController {
Pembayaran pembayaran=new Pembayaran();
FormPembayaran formPembayaran;
String pesan;
public String getPesan(){
    return pesan;
}
public void setPesan(String pesan){
    this.pesan=pesan;
}
public void simpan(JTextField bayar,JTextField kembalian,JTextField total){
    if(!bayar.getText().equals("")){
    pembayaran.setBayar(Integer.parseInt(bayar.getText()));
    pembayaran.setTotal(Integer.parseInt(total.getText()));
    pembayaran.setKembalian(Integer.parseInt(kembalian.getText()));

    if(pembayaran.simpan()){

        MainForm.formPembayaran.setTotal(0);
        MainForm.formPembayaran.setTerbilangTotal("");
        MainForm.formPembayaran.setTerbilangBayar("");
        MainForm.formPembayaran.setKembalian(0);
        MainForm.formPembayaran.setBayar(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sukses");
    }
    else{

        pesan="error : controller";
    }
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error dari kontroller : bayar tidak boleh kosong");
    }

}

}
```

this is view package

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    pembayaranController.simpan(bayarTextField, kembalianTextField, totalTextField);
}      
public void setBayar(int bayar){
    this.bayarTextField.setText(Integer.toString(bayar));
}
public int getBayar(){
    return Integer.parseInt(this.bayarTextField.getText());
}
public void setKembalian(int kembalian){
    this.kembalianTextField.setText(Integer.toString(kembalian));
}
public int getKembalian(){
    return Integer.parseInt(this.kembalianTextField.getText());
}
public void setTerbilangBayar(String terbilangBayar){
    this.terbilangBayarTextField.setText(terbilangBayar);
}
public String getTerbilangBayar(){
    return this.terbilangBayarTextField.getText();
}
public void setTerbilangTotal(String terbilangTotal){
    this.terbilangTotalTextField.setText(terbilangTotal);
}
public String getTerbilangTotal(){
    return this.terbilangTotalTextField.getText();
}
public void setTotal(int total){
    this.totalTextField.setText(Integer.toString(total));
}
public int getTotal(){
    return Integer.parseInt(this.totalTextField.getText());
}


 package model;

  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
```

this is database connection class

```
 public class Koneksi {

private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JualPulsa";
private static final String user = "andi";
private static final String password = "belajar";

private Connection connection;        
private String pesanKesalahan;

public String getPesanKesalahan() {
    return pesanKesalahan;
}

public Connection getConnection(){
    connection = null;        
    pesanKesalahan = "";

    try{ 
        Class.forName(driver); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){ 
        pesanKesalahan = "JDBC Driver tidak ditemukan atau rusak\n"+ex;
    } 

    if (pesanKesalahan.equals("")){ 
        try { 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(database+"?user="+user+"&password="+password+""); 
        } catch (SQLException ex) { 
            pesanKesalahan = "Koneksi ke "+database+" gagal\n"+ex;
        }
    }

    return connection;
}

 }
```

i have no error code to debug,, thats why im so strugling here , i hope i can solve this problem with your help... 
thanks b4..

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: i have no errors but the data just cannot be inserted to database.. it seems my program have a mistake but i dont knw where is it.. i just following the tutorials that i found in internet ...

Comment: What do you mean by *data just cannot be inserted to database*? Does it mean that the program executes but you cannot find any data in the database. Or does it mean that you have caught some exception somewhere and the program exits gracefully without executing the insert statement? Or does it just shows the "model error"?

Comment: i mean my programs is running with no errors, while i inserted to textfield and press the save button , then i check the data that i just saved in phpmyadmin, and there is no data in my database.. and my program have no caught  any exception from SQLException or other Exception

Comment: Are you sure that `koneksi.getConnection()` is not returning `null`? because if it is `null` then the inserting process does not occur. Also I noted that your `simpan` method is always going to return `true` whether the insert statement is executed or not

Comment: wait.. i'll check it and try it..

Comment: yes koneksi.getConnection() returning null...thanks for correcting me Blip ..